# Why am I receiving postmaster emails?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, exchange-migration

I'm in the process of migrating our environment from Exchange 2003 to 2010.  For a while now, I have been receiving messages from `postmaster@domain.com`, most of which look like this:

> *To:* Me
>
> *From:* postmaster@domain.com
>
> *Subject:* Blablabla
>
> *Content*:
>
> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> **userwhodoesn'texistanylonger@domain.com**
>
> The e-mail address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's e-mail address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: exchange2003server.domain.com
>
> userwhodoesn'texistanylonger@domain.com
>
> ## < #5.1.1> #SMTP
>
> Original message headers:
>
> Received: from iis_server ([IP address]) by exchange2003server.domain.com with Microsoft
>    SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);     Fri, 30 Nov 2012 06:11:54 -0800
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   From: Someone
>   To: 
>   Date: Fri, 30 Nov 2012 06:11:54 -0800
>   Subject: Blablabla
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   Return-Path: Someone
>   Message-ID: 
>   X-OriginalArrivalTime: 30 Nov 2012 14:11:54.0667 (UTC) FILETIME=[A6AB37B0:01CDCF04]

I received another message today that I believe was supposed to be quarantined (subject line was just `[QUAR]`) that was for another user entirely.

Why am I getting these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email address is designated as the email address to send a copy og NDR's to on the Messages tab of the Default SMTP Virtual Server on your Exchange 2003 server.

Comment: Herp, thanks very much.  No idea why that would have been configured like that.  I've removed my email address and presume I won't see these anymore.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...